# Can't scroll my webpage on phone

Tags: android, html, mobile, cordova

I added the following lines to my header, but when I try to view my webpage on an android device I can't scroll down.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

Any ideas why I can't scroll down?

Comment: What happens when you remove those lines? Perhaps there isn't enough content or some CSS is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have :

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Some webkit's browsers doesn't like this ;)
You should try to remove this rule.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that if a website contains elements with css position: fixed; the screen won't scroll in android devices. You should use position: absolute or relative instead.